# Output is displayed as integer instead of float in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the percentage of Married/Unmarried male and female employees.

This is the query:

```
SELECT
    MaritalStatus, Gender, 
    COUNT(*) AS "count",
    100 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HumanResources.Employee) AS percentage
FROM
    HumanResources.Employee he
GROUP BY
    MaritalStatus,Gender
```

This is the output:

[image]

Correct values for 'percentage' column should be 16.89, 12.06, 33.44 and 37.58.

How can I get these values?

Comment: Integer division..`…(100.0*count(*))/…`

Comment: Thanks. What if I don't multiply it by any number?

Comment: Then `CONVERT` one of the values to a `decimal` (I would strongly suggest `float` is the wrong data type) first. If your expression only consists of `int` values, then you will get an `int` value back.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have integer division. You need to convert at least one side to `decimal`, either by multiplying by `100.0` or `1.0`, or alternatively using `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

You can also improve your query by using a window function instead of a subquery. Note that the window function is calculated *after* aggregating, which is why you can put an aggregation function inside it `SUM(COUNT(*))`.

```sql
SELECT
    he.MaritalStatus,
    he.Gender, 
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    100 * CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(9,2)) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM
    HumanResources.Employee he
GROUP BY
    he.MaritalStatus,
    he.Gender
```

Answer (score 0):

The ISO standard SQL language has a strong data typing. When compute formulae involves integer the result will always be an integer, and this happened in your case.

Some RDBMS does not apparently conform to this rule, like Oracle Database, because Oracle does not have any integer nor float datatypes only DECIMAL.

So you must use an implicit conversion of datatype to solve your problem or use a trick with a non integer constant to do so...

First form can be :

```
SELECT MaritalStatus, Gender, 
       COUNT(*) AS count,
       100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM   HumanResources.Employee
GROUP  BY MaritalStatus, Gender
```

Second form can be :

```
SELECT MaritalStatus, Gender, 
       COUNT(*) AS count,
       CAST(100 AS DECIMAL (16, 3)) * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM   HumanResources.Employee
GROUP  BY MaritalStatus, Gender
```

I'll prefer typing a constant not a column, for performances reasons !